# How to remove Child control from its Parent without affecting Visibility

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have not found any previous question that handles my problem.
I have a Grid control called frontFace inside another Grid Control (wholeSurface). I am working with multiple page printing so I am assigning frontFace to a FixedPage fPage1 like this.

```
fPage1.Children.Add(frontFace);
```

Now, the problem is that frontFace now has 2 parents and yet it should have only one parent and an exception is thrown asking me to disconnect it. Now, if I clear the children of wholeSurface, everything works perfectly. But, of course, I can no longer see frontFace on wholeSurface. The USER MUST be able to see frontFace! How do I disconnect the child control without affecting its visibility?!!

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Simple and short answer: You cant. I suppose the Grid wholeSurface and FixedPage are part of the same visual tree and any wpf element can only be assigned to one of both. If you are trying to print the current screen, check the following [link](http://www.grumpydev.com/2009/01/03/taking-wpf-screenshots/)